# Android 4.4.2 with proguard java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: android, android-proguard

My Andorid application is using my custom android library and is obfuscated using proguard. It is running fine for Android 5.0+  but for Android 4.4.2 is gives java.lang.VerifyError in release mode (the proguard obfuscated) for the class contained in library. My proguard version is 4.7 and I am using AndroidStudio.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/sample/MyClass
                                                       at com.sample.implementation.ac.c(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.sample.b.d.j.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.sample.b.d.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.sample.b.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Please let me know if anyone has any idea for this.